# PF war file deployment on weblogic

Tags: jsf, weblogic

After trying to deploy war file on Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0 for past few days i keep getting this errors:

```
Unable to access the selected application.

VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND /domains/hnb_frtest/weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader@14809eda finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@494ac240 annotation: /WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.12.jar!/META-INF/web-fragment.xml:18:3:18:3: problem: cvc-enumeration-valid: string value '4.0' is not a valid enumeration value for web-app-versionType in namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee

VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND /domains/hnb_frtest/weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader@14809eda finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@494ac240 annotation: /WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.12.jar!/META-INF/web-fragment.xml:18:3:18:3: problem: cvc-enumeration-valid: string value '4.0' is not a valid enumeration value for web-app-versionType in namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee

VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND /domains/hnb_frtest/weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader@14809eda finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@494ac240 annotation: /WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.12.jar!/META-INF/web-fragment.xml:18:3:18:3: problem: cvc-enumeration-valid: string value '4.0' is not a valid enumeration value for web-app-versionType in namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee

Unable to access the selected application.

VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND /domains/hnb_frtest/weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader@7e1a4876 finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@37fb545a annotation: /WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar!/META-INF/web-fragment.xml:18:3:18:3: problem: cvc-enumeration-valid: string value '4.0' is not a valid enumeration value for web-app-versionType in namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee

VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND /domains/hnb_frtest/weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader@7e1a4876 finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@37fb545a annotation: /WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar!/META-INF/web-fragment.xml:18:3:18:3: problem: cvc-enumeration-valid: string value '4.0' is not a valid enumeration value for web-app-versionType in namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee

VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND /domains/hnb_frtest/weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader@7e1a4876 finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@37fb545a annotation: /WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar!/META-INF/web-fragment.xml:18:3:18:3: problem: cvc-enumeration-valid: string value '4.0' is not a valid enumeration value for web-app-versionType in namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
```

Has anyone encountered this error and if so what is the way to fix it?

P.S. I've read one answer about creating web.xml file and changing web-app versions but I've also tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Should war archives deployed on weblogic embed a tomcat?

Comment: Indeed. You're basically attempting to run a Tomcat server from a WAR deployed to WebLogic. Looks like you have a serious  XY-problem.

Comment: I apologize since I'm new to this, Tomcat is used to run my app localy, so when I'm trying to create war for deployment, i should remove all the tomcat jars/dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

@Kukeltje objects to the suggested solutions, e.g. "this question is about Wildfly not springboot and Tomcat. Totally off topic answer."

I don't understand the objection:  OP's original question mentions Tomcat six times, and @Kukeltje's comment is the first time Wildfly & springboot are mentioned here.

How is OP's question related to Wildfly / springboot, and how is it NOT related to Tomcat?

I have a similar issue, and the proposed dependency & exclusion fixes didn't work for me.

Answer (score -2):

you may insert this in pom.xml:

```
    <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
```

you have exclusion all libraries of Tomcat because Tomcat is for execute your aplication in Local but in weblogic Tomcat dont may stay.

Comment: Uhhhhh... this quesion is about Wildfly not springboot and tomcat. Totally off topic answer.

Answer (score -2):

Try this. Work for me:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: This is totally not related to the question... 0% Did you not see the downvoted other almost identical answer there and the comment on it?